# Wildcard in a list - Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

```
ArrayList<? extends A> array = new ArrayList<A>();
array.add(new A());
```

Why wouldnt this compile?

Comment: For future reference, you should also post the compiler error.

Answer (score 5):

Relevant part from the Java tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html):

> A list defined by List can be informally thought of as
>   read-only, but that is not a strict guarantee. Suppose you have the
>   following two classes:
>
> ```
> class NaturalNumber {
>
>     private int i;
>
>     public NaturalNumber(int i) { this.i = i; }
>     // ...
> }
>
> class EvenNumber extends NaturalNumber {
>
>     public EvenNumber(int i) { super(i); }
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Consider the following code:
>
> ```
> List<EvenNumber> le = new ArrayList<>();
> List<? extends NaturalNumber> ln = le;
> ln.add(new NaturalNumber(35));  // compile-time error
> ```
>
> Because `List<EvenNumber>` is a subtype of `List<? extends
>   NaturalNumber>`, you can assign le to ln. But you cannot use ln to add
>   a natural number to a list of even numbers.
>
> The following operations on the list are possible:
>
> - You can add null.
> - You can invoke clear.
> - You can get the iterator and invoke remove.
> - You can capture the wildcard and write elements that you've read from the list.
>
> You can see that the list defined by List is
>   not read-only in the strictest sense of the word, but you might think
>   of it that way because you cannot store a new element or change an
>   existing element in the list.

Another relevant explanation can be found here (his link also explains the issue of wildcards - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

> ...
>
> It isn't safe to add arbitrary objects to it however:
>
> ```
> Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
> c.add(new Object()); // Compile time error
> ```
>
> Since we don't know what the element type of c stands for, we cannot
>   add objects to it. The add() method takes arguments of type E, the
>   element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is ?,
>   it stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we pass to add would
>   have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what
>   type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is null,
>   which is a member of every type.
>
> On the other hand, given a List, we can call get() and make use of
>   the result. The result type is an unknown type, but we always know
>   that it is an object. It is therefore safe to assign the result of
>   get() to a variable of type Object or pass it as a parameter where the
>   type Object is expected.

Answer (score 2):

Since [we don't know](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)  what the element type of array stands for, we cannot add objects to it.

Instead, use a temporary list:

```
ArrayList<A> tempArray = new ArrayList<A>();
tempArray.add(new A())
tempArray.add(new A())

ArrayList<? extends A> array = tempArray;
```

An example of how to use it

//Vehicle

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

}
```

//Car

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

}
```

//HandlerVehicle

```
public class HandlerVehicle {

    private List<? extends Vehicle> _vehicles;

    public void addVehicles(List<? extends Vehicle> vehicles) {
        _vehicles = vehicles;
        //perform operations with Vehicle objects
    }

}
```

//HandlerCar

```
public class HandlerCar {
    private HandlerVehicle _handlerVehicle;
    private List<Car> _cars;

    public HandlerCar() {
        _cars = getCars();
        _handlerVehicle = new HandlerVehicle();
        _handlerVehicle.addVehicles(_cars);
    }

    private List<Car> getCars() {
        return new ArrayList<Car>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the last two lines of your code? You create an `ArrayList` and assign it to the reference `genericArray`. Then proceed to throw away the new list by assigning `genericArray`  to refer to the same list as `array`.

Comment: This will work and is no longer incorrect so I have removed my downvote. However, you can now use `tempArray` directly, so `array` is not really needed. Of course, maybe I'm missing a reason to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an `A` to a `List<? extends A>`. In order to fix your problem you should simply declare your list as

```
ArrayList<A> array = new ArrayList<A>();
```

Note that it is preferable to use an interface for the declaration:

```
List<A> array = new ArrayList<A>();
```

This allows you to easily change the concrete type at a later time because you only need to make a single change.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the declaration, the `array.add(new A());` is the problem since an `A` object cannot be added to a `List<? extends A>`

Comment: @Henry Hmm...I see. My solution still stands even though my explanation for the cause of the error is not valid.

Comment: Assume `B` extends `A` and you have `List<? extends A> l = new ArrayList<B>()`. It is clear that `l.add(new A())` would violate the integrity of the list.